# Extended Floorplan Example crashes after adding changes from Mira release

Tags: android, release, google-project-tango

When starting an app that was based on the [floor plan example](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-java/tree/master/java_floor_plan_example), the app crashes, the tango core crashes and the log consists of the following:

```
05-11 08:39:26.422 2893-2893/[applicationId] I/Rajawali: Rajawali | Anchor Steam | v1.0 
05-11 08:39:26.428 2893-2893/[applicationId] E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
05-11 08:39:26.435 2893-2893/[applicationId] D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so

                                                        [ 05-11 08:39:26.435  2893: 2893 I/      ]
                                                        Attempting to load EGL implementation libEGL_tegra_impl


                                                        [ 05-11 08:39:26.440  2893: 2893 I/      ]
                                                        Loaded EGL implementation libEGL_tegra_impl
05-11 08:39:26.441 2893-2893/[applicationId] D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so
05-11 08:39:26.443 2893-2893/[applicationId] D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
05-11 08:39:26.760 2893-2893/[applicationId] D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0

                                                             [ 05-11 08:39:26.859  1775: 1775 I/      ]
                                                             Loading GLESv2 implementation libGLESv2_tegra_impl
05-11 08:39:26.937 2893-2935/[applicationId] E/Rajawali: Getting location of uniform: uNormalMatrix returned -1!
05-11 08:39:26.937 2893-2935/[applicationId] E/Rajawali: Getting location of uniform: uModelMatrix returned -1!
05-11 08:39:26.937 2893-2935/[applicationId] E/Rajawali: Getting location of uniform: uModelViewMatrix returned -1!
05-11 08:39:26.937 2893-2935/[applicationId] E/Rajawali: Getting location of uniform: uTime returned -1!
05-11 08:39:26.938 2893-2935/[applicationId] E/Rajawali: Getting location of uniform: uNormalMatrix returned -1!
05-11 08:39:26.938 2893-2935/[applicationId] E/Rajawali: Getting location of uniform: uModelMatrix returned -1!
05-11 08:39:26.938 2893-2935/[applicationId] E/Rajawali: Getting location of uniform: uModelViewMatrix returned -1!
05-11 08:39:26.938 2893-2935/[applicationId] E/Rajawali: Getting location of uniform: uColor returned -1!
05-11 08:39:26.938 2893-2935/[applicationId] E/Rajawali: Getting location of uniform: uTime returned -1!
05-11 08:39:26.940 2893-2935/[applicationId] E/Rajawali: Getting location of uniform: uNormalMatrix returned -1!
05-11 08:39:26.940 2893-2935/[applicationId] E/Rajawali: Getting location of uniform: uModelMatrix returned -1!
05-11 08:39:26.940 2893-2935/[applicationId] E/Rajawali: Getting location of uniform: uModelViewMatrix returned -1!
05-11 08:39:26.940 2893-2935/[applicationId] E/Rajawali: Getting location of uniform: uColor returned -1!
05-11 08:39:26.940 2893-2935/[applicationId] E/Rajawali: Getting location of uniform: uTime returned -1!
05-11 08:39:29.190 2893-2893/[applicationId] I/TangoClientLibLoader: basePath: /data/data/com.projecttango.tango/libfiles/
05-11 08:39:29.191 2893-2893/[applicationId] E/art: dlopen("/data/data/com.projecttango.tango/libfiles/arm64-v8a/libtango_client_api.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/com.projecttango.tango/libfiles/arm64-v8a/libtango_client_api.so" not found
05-11 08:39:29.194 2893-2893/[applicationId] I/TangoClientLibLoader: Success! Using armeabi-v7a/libtango_client_api.
05-11 08:39:29.194 2893-2893/[applicationId] I/tango_client_api: TangoErrorType TangoService_setBinder(JNIEnv*, jobject): Passing back the binder on the client end...
05-11 08:39:29.197 2893-3115/[applicationId] I/tango_client_api: void* TangoService_getConfig(TangoConfigType): Getting config...
05-11 08:39:29.228 2893-3115/[applicationId] I/tango_client_api: void* TangoService_getConfig(TangoConfigType): Done getting config.
05-11 08:39:29.229 2893-3115/[applicationId] I/Tango: com.projecttango.tango version: 9377
05-11 08:39:29.229 2893-3115/[applicationId] I/tango_client_api: void* TangoService_getConfig(TangoConfigType): Getting config...
05-11 08:39:29.260 2893-3115/[applicationId] I/tango_client_api: void* TangoService_getConfig(TangoConfigType): Done getting config.
05-11 08:39:29.261 2893-3115/[applicationId] I/tango_client_api: TangoErrorType TangoService_connect(void*, TangoConfig): Connecting to Tango...
05-11 08:39:29.751 2893-3115/[applicationId] E/tango_client_api: TangoErrorType TangoService_connect(void*, TangoConfig): Internal Error: Connect failed internally: -1
05-11 08:39:29.751 2893-3114/[applicationId] E/tango: TangoClient.cc:26 Tango Service binder transaction failed! Transaction type code = 1, status = -32.
05-11 08:39:29.752 2893-2911/[applicationId] E/tango_client_api: virtual void TangoMortician::binderDied(const android::wp<android::IBinder>&): Internal Error: TangoService died.
05-11 08:39:29.752 2893-2911/[applicationId] A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 2911 (Binder_1)
05-11 08:39:29.754 2893-3115/[applicationId] E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-262
                                                             Process: [applicationId], PID: 2893
                                                             com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoErrorException
                                                               at com.google.atap.tangoservice.Tango.throwTangoExceptionIfNeeded(Tango.java:947)
                                                               at com.google.atap.tangoservice.Tango.connect(Tango.java:468)
                                                               at [applicationId].FloorplanActivity.connectTango(FloorplanActivity.java:248)
                                                               at [applicationId].FloorplanActivity.access$100(FloorplanActivity.java:86)
                                                               at [applicationId].FloorplanActivity$2.run(FloorplanActivity.java:222)
                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811)
```

I assume that my problem is not code specific but rather general, which is why I don't post any actual code here. I am not sure, what causes the error having not much experience. Anyone with more knowledge around? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there was no mistake with the MIRA release or my application of which, but a different feature, I added at the same time. My mistake. Can be closed.

Comment: Having the same issue here. How did you resolve this in the end? What was causing it?

Comment: I was doing to much work and the app worked for a really small amount of time, but then crashed before I realized that. I reduced the main work load again and as a result it worked again (well, it takes longer until it crashes but still crashes at the moment.